# Detect if USB device is Android phone

Tags: android, linux, windows

There is some way to detect if a USB device connected to the computer is an Android phone (in MTP data transfer mode)?

In my application I would like to show a list of connected devices and their respective names. In my case I am using Electron JS, however, any OS level information is appreciated now (Linux or Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about MTP mode but, there is **npm module** which provides wrapper for **adb** (Android Debug Bridge) has `adb devices` option to return **List** of attached devices.

You can get module from here - [Android Platform Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/android-platform-tools)

As you are working with electron framework, you can directly use npm module to use it in javascript